# Whack-A-Mole game with huge bug! Can I get some help fixing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a Whack-A-Mole game for class using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. I have run into a very interesting bug where, at seemingly random intervals, my moles with stop changing their "onBoard" variables and, as a result, will stop being assigned to the board. Something similar has also happened with the holes, but not as often in my testing. All of this is completely independent of user interaction.

You guys and gals are my absolute last hope before I scrap the project and start completely from scratch. This has frustrated me to no end. Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/CompostKicker/pen/wGBzae) and my [github](https://github.com/rrapstine/whackamole.dev) if you prefer to have the images.

Since Codepen links apparently require accompanying code, here is the function where I believe the problem is occuring.

```
// Run the game
    function run() {
        var interval = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) * 1000);

        if(firstRound) {
            renderHole(mole(), hole(), lifeSpan());
            firstRound = false;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            renderHole(mole(), hole(), lifeSpan());
            run();
        }, interval);
    }
```

What I believe is happening is this. The function runs at random intervals, between 0-6 seconds. If the function runs too quickly, the data that is passed to my renderHole() function gets overwritten with the new data, thus causing the previous hole and mole to never be taken off the board (variable wise at least).

EDIT: It turns out that my issue came from my not having returns on my recursive function calls. Having come from a different language, I was not aware that, in JavaScript, functions return "undefined" if nothing else is indicated. I am, however, marking GameAlchemist's answer as the correct one due to the fact that my original code was convoluted and confusing, as well as redundant in places. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Have you tried adding + 1000 to interval to make sure it's never 0?

Comment: Could you upload assets somewhere and update the codepen with external links to them?

Comment: Notice in line 124 you have `curHole.onBoard && holeCount >= 10`. Did you mean `curMole.onBoard`?

Comment: @Stiliyan Assets have been uploaded. Any yes, that is exactly what I meant. Thanks for catching that. The pen has been updated. Also, I have indeed added time to the interval to prevent a 0 second update, however even with a static interval of 3000 the problem still occurs. It just requires a bit of dumb luck.

Comment: @Stiliyan Correction, I did NOT mean that. I meant to check for data-mole on the hole's div. That is what the Pen was updated to. Just wanted to clear that up.

Comment: What is the purpose of the hole and mole counters? And the checks for greater or less than 10?

Comment: @Stiliyan The purpose of the counters is to prevent a stack overflow in the event that the functions are called too rapidly in succession. Ideally, this would never happen, but based on how my code it acting it was necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done here and there in your code some design mistakes that, one after another, makes the code hard to read and follow, and quite impossible to debug.
the `mole()` function might return a mole... or not... or create a timeout to call itself later.. what will be done with the result when `mole` calls itself again ? nothing, so it will just be marked as onBoard never to be seen again.
--->>> Have a clear definition and a single responsibility for `mole()`: for instance 'returns an available non-displayed mole character or null'. And that's all, no count, no marking of the objects, just KISS (Keep It Simple S...) :  it should always return a value and never trigger a timeout.
Quite the same goes for `hole()` : return a free hole or null, no marking, no timeout set.

`render` should be simplified : get a mole, get a hole, if either couldn't be found bye bye. If a mole+hole was found, just setup the new mole/hole couple + event handler (in a separate function). Your main `run` function will ensure to try again and again to spawn moles.

Comment: Apologies if I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be; I'm pretty worn out at this point in the day. So basically, I should remove the count from mole() and hole(), change renderHole() to only display the combo and make a separate function for the click listener logic upon successfully placing a mole?

Comment: We're here to learn. Your design is quite good in fact, you just have to keep it simple, break it down in very simple functions doing only one thing simple to describe. Maybe improve the names also : `getNextMole`and `getNextHole`instead of `mole` / `hole`, for instance.